# PNaCl logging to stdout no longer working in Chrome 72 onwards?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

I'm currently working to maintain an existing PNaCl application for ChromeOS devices. Prior to Chrome 72, we were able to log to stdout and stderr and these logs would appear on the ChromeOS device inside the ui.LATEST file. Since our ChromeOS devices have upgraded to versions past Chrome 71 our logs do not appear any more. We've tried this on devices running both Intel and ARM chipsets with the same results. We are using Pepper 49 (the latest). Our development environments in Ubuntu are still outputting to the stdout and stderr.

Has there been a change in Chrome 72 to where stdout and stderr log to or how we log to the ui.LATEST file?

EDIT: We've tried a couple of other sites that we know log to the stdout and use PNaCl, namely this: https://gonativeclient.appspot.com/demo - this also does not log to the Chromebooks but does log in our development environments.

Comment: Could be a bug or an intended change. Try [bisecting](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py) and/or report on https://crbug.com